# How do manage custom fields for client specific (branding) purposes

Tags: mysql, salesforce, custom-fields, saas, netsuite

We are developing an enterprise application which provides cloud storage services for its clients (via Software As A Service). Some of our clients want to track users coming from their web portal (landing page) by adding some custom fields specific to that client (example: license type, key, serial number etc). At this point, we only have one client which uses our application and provides services to its end users, but we are negotiating with a new client which will use our service as well in near future.

At this point, we have a **relational** database (MySql) table specific to that first client which we use to handle that client's custom fields, and we don't want to create tables specific to the new client's custom fields as it would require changing the database schema every time we add a new client to our application.

Our research has indicated that there are few methods we could use for our relational databse to solve our problem. They are  (Source: http://www.percona.com/live/mysql-conference-2013/sites/default/files/slides/Extensible%20Data%20Modeling.pdf):

1. Adding Extra columns (in a custom field table)
2. Entity - Attribute - Value Model
3. Class Table Inheritance Model
4. Serialized LOB & Inverted Indexes

**Our question is : How do mature companies (specifically like Salesforce, NetSuite etc) store custom fields in the database architecturally and how should we store them?**

Any help / pointers in the right direction would be helpful. Thanks.